# Flutter - Import model in other model

Tags: flutter, dart, model

In **Flutter** i have two models. We can call Father and Son.

The Son model is

```
 class GraphData {
      int timestamp;
      double value;
      bool error;

  GraphData({
    this.timestamp,
    this.value,
    this.error,
  });

  factory GraphData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new GraphData(
        timestamp: json["x"],
        value: json["y"],
        error: json["error"],
      );
}
```

And The Father model

```
import 'graph_data_model.dart';

class Graph {
  String name;
  List<GraphData> data; 
  int type;

  Graph({
    this.name,
    this.data,
    this.type,
  });

  factory Graph.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new Graph(
        name: json["name"],
        data: json['data'], //Error here
        type: json["type"],
      );
}
```

I want to import Son in Father models. With this code returns

_TypeError (type 'List < dynamic > ' is not a subtype of type 'List < GraphData >')

So: What's the right way to do this?

**SOLUTION**

Son model

```
import 'graph_data_model.dart';

class Graph {
  String name;
  List<GraphData> data;
  int type;

  Graph({
    this.name,
    this.data,
    this.type,
  });

  factory Graph.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var list = json['data'] as List;
    List<GraphData> data = list.map((i) => GraphData.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return Graph(
      name: json["name"],
      data: data,
      type: json["type"],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: at what line is this error thrown

Comment: In  data: json['data'] of the father model.

Comment: You need to parse `json['data']`

Comment: I copy pasted your code and put each class in a file and got no errors

Comment: @SantoshAnand How can i parse it?

Comment: You mean the error is before you run the code or at runtime?If before runtime I am not getting any errors with your code

Comment: The error appear at runtime.

Comment: so can you provide code of how you are using json['data']

Answer (score 0):

The error `_TypeError (type 'List <dynamic> ' is not a subtype of type 'List <GraphData>')` occurs because the deserialized List returned from the json is `List<dynamic>` and cannot be mapped directly to a `List<GraphData>`. It's unable to identify if the Object from the deserialized List matches GraphData.

What you can do here is parse `List<dynamic>` from `json['data']` then map it to `List<GraphData>`.

```dart
return Graph(
  name: json['name'],
  data: (json['data'] as List).map((model)=> GraphData.fromJson(model)).toList(),
  type: json['type'],
);
```